# Prove Transformation is one-to-one iff it carries linearly independent subsets of $V$ onto Lin. Ind. subsets of $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

A textbook example asks you to prove that for the linear transformation $T\colon V \to W$ that it is one-to one if and only if $T$ carries linearly independent subsets of $V$ onto linearly independent subsets of $W$.

The answer key gives the following solution:

> Suppose $T$ is one-to-one.
>   Then let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$, and let $S' = \{T(s)\mid s \in S\}$. (Notice that we’re not assuming that $S$ is finite.) Suppose there are some
>   elements of $S’$ $T(s_1), T(s_2), \ldots , T(s_n)$ and scalars $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ such that $a_1T(s_1)+ \cdots + a_nT(s_n) = 0$. Then by the linearity of $T$,
>
> $a_1T(s_1) + . . . + a_nT(s_n) = 0$
>
> $T(a_1s_1) + . . . + T(a_ns_n) = 0$
>
> $T(a_1s_1 + . . . + a_ns_n) = 0$
>
> But $T$ is one-to-one, so $a_1s_1 + \cdots + a_ns_n = 0$, and thus $a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 0$
>   because $S$ is linearly independent. Thus $S’$ is linearly independent.

I don't understand this solution. Why does $(a_1s_1+...a_ns_n)$ need to equal 0 just because $T(\text{stuff}) = 0$?  A one-to-one function doesn't mean that $T(1) = 1$ and $T(2) = 2$ etc... It simply means all numbers in the codomain must appear in the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-to-one (or injective) function doesn't mean that the codomain must appear in the range. Those are called **onto** or **surjective** functions. One-to-one means that for any output, there is exactly one input that maps to it (one output - to - one input).

$$L(\mathbf{x}) = L(\mathbf{y}) \implies \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}$$

You may want to contrast the two types:

1. One-to-one functions have **at most** one input for each vector in the codomain.
2. Onto or surjective functions have **at least** one input for each vector in the codomain.

If you combine the two, you have **exactly one** input for each vector in the codomain. That's precisely the definition of a bijection mapping.

As for the above theorem, the more fundamental result is perhaps that a linear mapping is one-to-one if and only if it has a trivial kernel. The proof of this is rather simple.

If $L$ is a linear mapping with a trivial kernel, then
$$L(\mathbf{x}) = L(\mathbf{y}) \implies L(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{0}$$
since the kernel is trivial we must have $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}$ so that the mapping is injective.

If conversely $L$ is injective, then since $L(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ this automatically implies $$L(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0} = L(\mathbf{0})\implies \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$

Applying the above result should yield what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $T$ is not one-to-one (I prefer "injective") so that there exist $v_1\neq v_2$ with $T(v_1)=T(v_2)$. Then by linearity $T(v_1-v_2)=0$, so that $\{v_1-v_2\}$ is a linearly independent subset whose image $\{0_W\}$ is linearly dependent. This proves the "if" part.

Now suppose $T$ is injective, $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ a linearly independent, and $c_iT(v_1)+\cdots+c_kT(v_k)=0$ a relation between their images. Then by linearity $T(c_iv_1+\cdots+c_kv_k)=c_iT(v_1)+\cdots+c_kT(v_k)=0_W=T(0_V)$ (the last equality is what you missed), so by injectivity $c_iv_1+\cdots+c_kv_k=0_v$ and by linear independence of the $v_i$ all coefficients $c_i$ have to be $0$; this shows that $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_k)$ are linearly independent. This proves the "f" part.

I did write the proof so that the independent set was finite, but your proposed answer shows how that can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

No, incorrect. Being one-to-one means that whenever $T(x) = T(y)$ for some $x$ and $y$ we must have that $x = y$. (The property you referr to is being 'onto').

Now, in your case, we have (as $T$ is linear and hence $T(0) = 0$, that 
$$
T \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_is_i\right) = 0 = T(0) \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i = 0 .
$$