# Proving two basic results about linear maps without requiring rank-nullity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $U,V$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. I've proven the following statements as easy consequences of the rank-nullity theorem. But now I'm curious as to how to prove them directly without requiring this theorem. I haven't had any success, however, and would appreciate seeing how it is done.

1. There exists a surjective $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ if and only if $\dim U \geq \dim V$.
2. There exists an injective $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ if and only if $\dim V \geq \dim U$.

Note: the scalars are from $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. (I realize now that any field will work, so disregard this stipulation if it's easier.)

Comment: Are they $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @DHMO I added a note saying what the scalars are.

Comment: And the vectors?

Comment: @DHMO arbitrary

Comment: How do you define dimension for an arbitrary vector?

Comment: @DHMO This is true for all finite dimensional vector spaces over any field...

Comment: @DHMO The dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of any basis of the space (which is well-defined as every basis has same number of elements)

Comment: @KenDuna Oh cool I'm currently studying just $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @KenDuna Even finite fields?

Comment: @DHMO Yes. This holds for any field.

Comment: @KenDuna I'm not seeing how there can be a surjective linear transformation from $\Bbb F_2^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$...

Comment: @DHMO $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces over the same field....

Comment: @KenDuna When did you say that?

Comment: @DHMO If that isn't clear to you, you shouldn't be answering any questions on linear algebra.

Comment: @KenDuna maybe the OP should be clarifying this instead of me not answering any questions on linear algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following facts about injective and surjective linear maps.

> Let $T\colon U \to V$ be a linear function and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ is a basis of the vector space $U$.
>
> - $T$ is injective if and only if the vectors $T(b_1),\dots,T(b_n)\in V$ are linearly independent.
> - $T$ is surjective if and only if the vectors $T(b_1),\dots,T(b_n)$ generate $V$, i.e., $[T(b_1),\dots,T(b_n)]=V$.

See also [Prove that the linear transformation is injective iff $T(f_1),\ldots,T(f_n)$ are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992989/prove-that-the-linear-transformation-is-injective-iff-tf-1-ldots-tf-n-are) for a proof of the first one.

Comment: If one is worrying about exactly which theorems one is using, I think I'd add these two for completeness: "Any LI set can be expanded to a  basis" and "Any generating set contains a basis".

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, those are exactly the results which will be needed. Thanks for the comment - I think it might be useful for some users. (I wanted to leave at least a bit to fill in by the OP. Of course, feel free to post an answer containing all details. I'd say it is quite common that questions on this site receive several answer which might differ in the amount of the details included in them.)

Answer (score -2):

### 1. There exists a surjective $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ if and only if $\dim U \geq \dim V$.

Let $u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_m$ be a basis of $U$ and $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n$ a basis of $V$.

#### For the "if" part:

Define $T$ as follows:

$$T(a_i) = \begin{cases}b_i & 1 \le i \le n \\ 0 & n < i \le m \end{cases}$$

The proof of its surjectivity is left as an exercise to the reader.

#### For the "only if" part:

(work in progress)

### 2. There exists an injective $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$ if and only if $\dim V \geq \dim U$.

The proof is left as an exercise to the reader.