# 2 Part one-to-one linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose that $T: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ is linear and one-to-one.  Let $\{\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \cdots, \vec{v}_k\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $R^n$ 
a) Prove that the set $\{T(\vec{v}_1), T(\vec{v}_2), \cdots, T(\vec{v}_k)\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $R^m$.
b) Show by example that (a) is false if $T$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @TheoBendit your link directs here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove Transformation is one-to-one iff it carries linearly independent subsets of $V$ onto Lin. Ind. subsets of $W$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207798/prove-transformation-is-one-to-one-iff-it-carries-linearly-independent-subsets-o)

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the details in the following proof.

Proof: Let $a_1,\dots,a_k$ be scalars such that $$a_1Tv_1+\dots+a_kTv_k=0$$ Now use the linearity of $T$ and use the theorem that if $T$ is a one-to-one linear map, then null$(T)=\{0\}$ to conclude that $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_k$ is linearly independent.

The question in part $b$ is wrong as it is not true. Consider the linear map $T : R^3\to R^3$ defined by $$T(x, y, z)=(x, y, 0)$$ Now see for yourself what happens to the linearly independent set $\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$ after you apply the above defined linear map to it.